# How to enable access from on-premise kubernetes to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I'm new to on-premise kubernetes cluster, and am having hard time accessing the AWS services such as ECR. (As all my images are in ECR)
Is there a way to authenticate and authorize on-premise kubernetes cluster to AWS?

Comment: have you tried seting up aws profile that your sdk or cli commands would be using?